# Query db for a model including related_model, where related model have 2 specific ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

In a rails app, i have a 3 models, Room, User and UsersRoom which is an association table between Room and User.
I want to query for a Room related to multiple users.

If i do:

```rb
Room.includes(:users_rooms).where(users_rooms: { user_id: user_ids }
```

I get all the room with at least one users_room containing one users_ids.
I want to get the room with users_rooms present for each user_ids.

Is there a clean way to do this without have to loop on the rooms after querying them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following:

```
Room
  .select('rooms.*, COUNT(users_rooms.user_id)')
  .joins(:users_rooms)
  .where(users_rooms: { user_id: user_ids })
  .group('rooms.id')
  .having('COUNT(users_rooms.user_id) >= ?', user_ids.size)
```

Notes:

- The `COUNT` in the `select` is required because some database engine versions complain when using `COUNT` in the `having` without having it defined in the `select` part. You can try to remove that line.
- The `join` does a `INNER JOIN` between both tables.
- The `where` is want you already had.
- The `group` groups the found records into a single line and allows using `COUNT`.
- The `having` only returns those `rooms` that had at least `user_ids.size` `users_rooms` associated.

Comment: Selecting the count isn't really useful unless you assign it an alias.

Comment: that's exactly what i wanted, thanks for the notes.

I set the post as resolve, but have an other question in my mind (not usefull atm but I guess it could be later)

I tried to modify it to have only the rooms that have exactly `user_ids.size` `users_rooms` associated.
I just changed the having method to:
`having('COUNT(users_rooms.user_id) = ?', user_ids.size)`
But it's still returning room with more that `user_ids.size`, did i miss something about `having`?

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
class Room
  # ...
  has_many :users, though: :users_rooms
end
```

```
Room.group(:id)
    .joins(:users)
    .where(users: { id: user_ids })
    .having(User.arel_table[:id].count.gte(user_ids.size))
```

Creating the indirect assocation is optional but the abstraction makes it so that your query isn't bound to how the join table is implemented.

For example `UsersRoom` isn't a great name and you might want to call it something more fitting like `Booking` - this lets you do that without breaking anything.

Comment: this looks cool, i'll need to invest a bit on what's going on exactly here and see what sql is performed to compare it to spikkerman response.

Yes i should probably rename it.

Comment: The basic approach is very simiar to spickermann's answer except that the conditions are set on the users table instead of the join table and that Arel is used instead of SQL strings.   `.having(User.arel_table[:id].count.gte(user_ids.size))` creates `HAVING COUNT("users"."id") >= x`.